# Would there be any damage reversing with my hand brake on in a motorhome?

Tags: brakes, motorhome

I was parking on a slope, I put the handbrake on and got out to check the back. When I returned I forgot the handbrake was on. When it didn't move I realised the handbrake was still on, I quickly released the handbrake,

Comment: You should be fine. A little extra wear on your brake pads, but nothing to worry about. I've left my parking brake on the highway before, and the parking brake still worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

That should not cause any damage.

Driving several miles at 60mph will cause damage though - seen the effects : blue discs and lots of smoke (luckily it was not me :) )